# How do I track if activity has ended Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity to add an object to a database in my application, and the database is displayed in activity which calls an `AddActivity`. My problem is I need to refresh ArrayList after i update a database, but i can't have access to it inside my `AddActivity`. So i wanted to track in `MainActivity` when the `AddActivity` has ended and then call the refreshing `function`. For now i tried using code below and this is working, but i don't think this is the way i should do it, I feel like there is better function for that but I couldn't find it.

Code in MainActivity inside `onClickListener`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ExerciseAdd.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Code in AddActivity also inside `onClickListener`:

```
dataBaseAccess = ExercisesDataBaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                dataBaseAccess.open();
                dataBaseAccess.addExercise(nameString, typeString, "NULL");
                dataBaseAccess.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("result", 1);
                setResult(1, intent);
                finish();
```

And refhresing function in `MainActivity`:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        dataBaseAccess.open();
        exercises = dataBaseAccess.getAllExercises();
        dataBaseAccess.close();
        adapter.setExercises(exercises);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Or maybe is there any way to pass an reference to `ArrayList` to `AddActivity`? it was hard to me to find any information about this

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it is the most robust and clean way. You are storing your data in the database and you have one `Activity` that adds items to the database and another `Activity` that reads the data from the database and displays it. This may seem like overkill, but this architecture is more robust than sharing data in memory between activities.

Of course, it is possible to share data in memory between activities. You can store a reference to your `ArrayList<Exercise>` in a `public static` variable and it can be accessed by both activities. This is a simple way to share data but can be tricky if your app goes to the background and Andriod kills off the OS process hosting the app and then the user returns to the app. If he was last using the `AddActivity`, when he returns to the app, Android will create a new OS process to host the app and instantiate the `AddActivity`, but `MainActivity` is not yet instantiated and your shared `public static` data will be gone. So this approach is error-prone.

Another approach would be to use Live Data. This is a more complicated approach to sharing data in memory between activities. You can read more about live data here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpfull for me

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will give me some reputation points, improve your accept rate and also help others who may have a similar problem.